# Adding My Own Credentials to git bash

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I am using a Windows system where git bash is already installed and someone's credentials are already configured, I want to remove their credentials and work with my own credentials. So what should I do for that?

Comment: https://help.github.com/articles/setting-your-username-in-git/

Comment: Why is someone elses credentials already specified? Are you using a shared computer?

Comment: He was a old employee and his credentials are specified, Now I am using that system.